# C# create object dynamically and set each parameter with loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor

Is there any way to fill up the variables of a dynamically created instance?

Something like:

```
var generatedRow = Activator.CreateInstance(listTables[typeToAdd]);

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in generatedRow.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    generatedRow.prop = 1;
}
```

NOTE: The code below is not meant to work, it's just an idea of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Have you looked into Dynamics? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/walkthrough-creating-and-using-dynamic-objects

Comment: Use reflection or `DynamicObject`.

Comment: Build each complex object off of a base class. The base class would have all of the common properties. You want to try to avoid Reflection as it is slower than other approaches

Comment: The desire to do this almost always indicates a design failure earlier in the process that will require significant refactoring to correct. Sometimes you opt to push forward anyway because it's too late, but the design failure is still there.

Comment: It is a design failure, im refactoring the code a bit, but i will leave the answer below  as good since it does what i asked for and someone might need that code in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the prop variable to set the value of the object that you created using the Activator.

```
    public class Car {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Color {get;set;}
    }

    var carType = typeof(Car);
    
    var carInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(carType);
    
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in carInstance.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        prop.SetValue(carInstance, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
    
    
    //DEMOSTRATION ONLY
    Console.WriteLine(((Car)carInstance).Name);
    Console.WriteLine(((Car)carInstance).Color);
```